# HackerRank Designer Door Mat

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve a problem in HackerRank and stuck in this.
Help me to write python code for this question

Mr. Vincent works in a door mat manufacturing company. One day, he designed a new door mat with the following specifications:

Mat size must be X. ( is an odd natural number, and  is  times .)
The design should have 'WELCOME' written in the center.
The design pattern should only use |, . and - characters.
Sample Designs

```
Size: 7 x 21 
---------.|.---------
------.|..|..|.------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
-------WELCOME-------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
------.|..|..|.------
---------.|.---------
```

Comment: What is actually the problem and what is your question?

Comment: Obviously it's a new user who just need a little bit help to start learning Python. First steps are the hardest. Let's be friendly.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most concise answer in python3 would be the following:

```
    N, M = map(int,input().split())
    for i in range(1,N,2): 
        print((i * ".|.").center(M, "-"))
    print("WELCOME".center(M,"-"))
    for i in range(N-2,-1,-2): 
        print((i * ".|.").center(M, "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a Simplified Version--

```
n,m = input().split()
n = int(n)
m = int(m)
#printing first half
for i in range(n//2):
    t = int((2*i)+1)
    print(('.|.'*t).center(m, '-'))
#printing middle line
print('WELCOME'.center(m,'-'))
#printing last half
for i in reversed(range(n//2)):
    t = int((2*i)+1)
    print(('.|.'*t).center(m, '-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses list comprehension. There is a tutorial on this [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension)

```py
# Using list comprehension
n, m = map(int, input().split())
pattern = [('.|.'*(2 * i + 1)).center(m,'-') for i in range(n//2)]
print('\n'.join(pattern + ['WELCOME'.center(m, '-')] + pattern[::-1]))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

every seems to missing the first hint . the input should be from stdin and out put should read to stdout .

Answer (score 0):

```py
n, m = map(int, input().split()) 
str1 = ".|."
half_thickness = n-2

for i in range(1,half_thickness+1,2):
    print((str1*i).center(m,"-"))

print("WELCOME".center(m,"-"))

for i in reversed(range(1,half_thickness+1,2)):
    print((str1*i).center(m,"-"))
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT

length, breadth = map(int, input().split())

def out(n,string):
    for i in range(n):
        print ("{}".format(string), end='')

def print_out(hyphen_count,polka_count):
    out(hyphen_count, '-')
    out(polka_count, '.|.')
    out(hyphen_count, '-')
    print ('')

hyphen_count = (breadth - 3) // 2
polka_count = 1
for i in range(length):
    if i < (length // 2):
        print_out(hyphen_count,polka_count)        
        hyphen_count = hyphen_count - 3
        polka_count = polka_count + 2
    elif i == (length // 2 + 1):
        out((breadth - 7)//2, '-')
        print ("WELCOME", end='')
        out((breadth - 7)//2, '-')
        print ('')
        hyphen_count = hyphen_count + 3
        polka_count = polka_count - 2        
    elif (length // 2) < i < length:
        print_out(hyphen_count,polka_count)        
        hyphen_count = hyphen_count + 3
        polka_count = polka_count - 2 
print_out(hyphen_count,polka_count)
```

Answer (score -1):

I was curious to look if there was a better solution to this hackerrank problem than mine so I landed up here.

#### My solution with a single `for` loop which successfully passed all the test cases:

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    row_num, column_num = map(int, input().split())
    
    
    num_list = []
    
    # take user input N and M as stated in the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/designer-door-mat
    # where N are the number of rows and M are the number of coulmns
    # For this explanation we assume N(row_num)=7, M(column_num)=21 for simplicity, 
    # the code below works on all the test cases provided by hackerrank and has cleared the submission
    
    
    # this for loop is for iterating through the number of rows: 0th row to (n-1)th row
    for i in range(0, row_num):
        
        # steps to be done at each row
        if i < row_num//2:
            # BEFORE REACHING THE MIDDLE OF THE DOOR MAT
            
            # we need to generate a pattern of ".|." aligned with '-' in the following manner: 
            # steps below will generate ".|." pattern 1, 3, 5 times 
            # On i=0, times = 2*(0+1)-1 = 1 => ---------.|.---------
            # On i=1, times = 2*(1+1)-1 = 3 => ------.|..|..|.------
            # On i=2, times = 2*(2+1)-1 = 5 => ---.|..|..|..|..|.---
            times = 2*(i+1)-1
            
            # record these numbers since we need to do the reverse when we reach the middle of the "door mat"
            num_list.append(times)
            
            # recall the assignment on Text Alignment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/text-alignment/problem
            # since that idea will be used below - at least this is how I look.
            
            # Essentially, this part of code helps to eliminate the need of a for loop for iterating through each columns to generate '-'
            # which would otherwise have to be used to print '-' surrounding the pattern .|. in each row
            # instead we can use the column number "M" from the user input to determine how much alignment is to be done
            print(('.|.'*times).center(column_num, '-'))
        
        
        elif i == (row_num//2):
            # UPON REACHING EXACTLY IN THE MIDDLE OF THE DOOR MAT
            # once middle of the row is reached, all we need to print is "WELCOME" aligned with '-' : -------WELCOME-------
            print('WELCOME'.center(column_num, '-'))
        else:
        # AFTER CROSSING THE MIDDLE OF THE DOOR MAT
        # as soon as we cross the middle of the row, we need to print the same pattern as done above but this time in reverse order
        # thankfully we have already stored the generated numbers in a list which is num_list = [1, 3, 5]
        # all we need to do is just fetch them one by one in reverse order
        # which is what is done by: num_list[(row_num-1)-i]
        # row_num = 7, i = 4, num_list[(7-1)-4] --> num_list[2] --> 5 => ---.|..|..|..|..|.---
        # row_num = 7, i = 5, num_list[(7-1)-5] --> num_list[1] --> 3 => ------.|..|..|.------
        # row_num = 7, i = 6, num_list[(7-1)-6] --> num_list[0] --> 1 => ---------.|.---------
        print(('.|.'*num_list[(row_num-1)-i]).center(column_num, '-'))
        
        # DONE!
```

Answer (score -1):

```
N, M = map(int, input().split())
d = ".|."
for i in range(N//2):
    print((d*i).rjust(M//2-1,'-') + d + (d*i).ljust(M//2-1,'-'))
print("WELCOME".center(M,'-'))
for j in range(N//2+2,N+1):
    print((d*(N-j)).rjust(M//2-1,'-') + d + (d*(N-j)).ljust(M//2-1,'-'))
```

Comment: When answering a question, please do not just drop some code. It is important to also explain what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
if you do not want to use any align keyword then. It is complicate to understand but diff. approch.

n, m = map(int,input().split())

i = m
i = int(i-3)
f = 1

for j in range(-i,n-3,6):
    j = abs(j)
    
    if j > 0:
        j = int(j/2)
        print(('-'*j)+('.|.'*f)+('-'*j))
        f = f+2
    else:
        f = f-2
        break

wel = int(m-7)
wel = int(wel/2)
print(('-'*wel)+'WELCOME'+('-'*wel))


for j in range(3,i,3):
    j = abs(j)
    
    if f > 0:
        print(('-'*j)+('.|.'*f)+('-'*j))
        f = f-2
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score -3):

```
N,M = map(int,raw_input().split())
count = 1
for _ in range(1,N/2+1):
    print ((".|."*count).center(M,"-"))
    count = count+2
print("WELCOME").center(M,"-")
count = count-2
for _ in range(1,N/2+1):
    print ((".|."*count).center(M,"-"))
    count = count-2
```

Comment: This answer does not explain why it works. How can one learn from it?

Comment: Elaborating on what @GooDeeJAY said: An answer is not worth much without context. It's not too difficult to find code that works, but understanding *why* it works is what's important.